# Returning unique paths with Gremlin in Java

Tags: java, groovy, gremlin

I'm having an issue with Gremlin returning duplicate paths and I was wondering if anyone could help me. I'm rather new to Gremlin so appologies if I make any simple mistakes.

A simple form of my database consists of over 50 nodes and over 5000 edges where edges are considered one directional, however between two nodes there may be edges going both ways causing a cyclical structure (So node A -> B -> A), likewise you could have (A -> B -> C -> A).

What I am trying to accomplish is a traversal of the network, returning every unique path between the start node and end node, which does not have a cycle. Below is an example of my code.

```
final List<List> paths = new ArrayList<List>();
String endNodeID = endNode.getVertex().getId().toString();
new GremlinPipeline<Vertex, ArrayList<Vertex>>(startNode.getVertex())
    .as("x").out("OutboundLink").simplePath()
    .loop("x", new PipeFunction<LoopPipe.LoopBundle<Vertex>, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean compute(final LoopPipe.LoopBundle<Vertex> loopBundle) {
                    return loopBundle.getLoops() <= 8;
                }
            }, new PipeFunction<LoopPipe.LoopBundle<Vertex>, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean compute(final LoopPipe.LoopBundle<Vertex> loopBundle) {
                    return endNodeID.equals(loopBundle.getObject().getId().toString());
                }
            }).simplePath().filter(new PipeFunction<Vertex, Boolean>() {

                @Override
                public Boolean compute(final Vertex arg0) {
                    return targetId.equals(arg0.getId().toString());
                }
            }).path(new PipeFunction<Vertex, String>() {
                @Override
                public String compute(final Vertex vertex) {
                    return vertex.getId().toString();
                }
            }).fill(paths);
```

What I believe it does

- Get the start vertex
- Declare a location as X
- Follow all OutboundLinks to X
- Remove any paths with cycle (e.g. A -> B-> C -> D-> B-> E)
- Loop back to X up to 8 times, however if a path gets to end node, stop that path progressing further.
- Recheck for cyclical paths.
- Filter for paths than end at the endNode.
- Populate the list.

From this I am currently getting the following unwanted behaviour
 - Duplicate paths
 - Paths that hit the endNodeID but have continued.

While I can correct this in code afterwards (In one simulation it corrects from 10000 paths to only 200), it does seem like a waste of resources.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Titan 0.5.4 I never got `simplePath()` to work for me either. The API doc suggests that its purpose is to detect and filter out out looping paths, but could be a misinterpretation on my side. What I ended up with is writing my own loop detection code.

Example graph:

```
            +--+        
     +------+V1+------+ 
     |      +--+      | 
     v                | 
              ^       | 
     +--+     |       v 
     |V2+-----+          
     |  |            +--+
     +--+ <----------+V3|
     |               ++-+
     |                | 
     |                | 
     |                | 
     |      +--+      | 
     +----> |V4| <----+ 
            +--+
```

The following code yields the paths

- v1->v2->v4
- v1->v3->v4
- v1->v3->v2->v4

Gremlin Pipeline:

```
public static List<List<Element>> findPathsBetweenSimple(final Vertex from, final Vertex to) {
    final Object endID = to.getId();
    GremlinPipeline<Vertex, List<Element>> pipe = new GremlinPipeline<>(from);
    pipe.as("startAt")
            .out()
            .loop("startAt", new PipeFunction<LoopBundle<Vertex>, Boolean>() {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                public Boolean compute(LoopBundle<Vertex> lb) {
                    Boolean doContinue = Boolean.TRUE;
                    LOG.trace("Loop cnt: " + lb.getLoops() + "; Vertex: " + lb.getObject());
                    if (containsLoop(lb.getPath(), lb.getObject())) {
                        LOG.debug("Loop detected in path. Aborting. " + lb.getPath());
                        doContinue = Boolean.FALSE;
                    } else if (endID.equals(lb.getObject().getId())) {
                        LOG.debug("Path found: " + lb.getPath() + ", " + lb.getObject());
                        doContinue = Boolean.FALSE;
                    }
                    return doContinue;
                }
            })
            .has("id", endID)
            .path();
    return pipe.toList();
}
```

Loop detection:

```
private static boolean containsLoop(final List<Element> path, Vertex current) {
    boolean loopDetected = false;

    final List<Vertex> vPath = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Element element : path) {
        if (element instanceof Vertex) {
            vPath.add((Vertex) element);
        }
    }
    vPath.add(current);

    for (Vertex v : vPath) {
        if (Collections.frequency(vPath, v) > 1) {
            loopDetected = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return loopDetected;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've used this and with some tweaks I've managed to get it to work and modified it to implement Dijkstra's algorithm. Thanks again.